# Are all ERC-20 tokens automatically traded on decentralized dapp exchanges?

Tags: erc-20

When a new token is issued, how does it get traded if it's not on one the big commercial exchanges? Are all ERC-20 tokens automatically traded on decentralized dapp exchanges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No they are not automatically traded on decentralised exchanges or what is also known as DEX. 
 However, if the token is transferable (no pause functionality or similar active, which can be seen by inspecting the contract), then anyone can add it for trade on DEX exchanges such as Etherdelta or IDEX.

Comment: Thanks. Do only the token owner suggest it's addition or can anybody?

Comment: anybody can do it